# React-Native 0.57.5 React Navigation 3 not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Hi i have created a fresh app.

- react-native init AwesomeProject
- cd AwesomeProject
- npm install --save react-navigation
- npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
- react-native link
- react-native run-ios

Error every time. if anyone has any ideals how to overcome this problem that would be great

```
TypeError: instance.render is not a function. (In 'instance.render()', 'instance.render' is undefined)

This error is located at:
    in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.js:300)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewLayout.js:298)
    in Handler (at StackViewLayout.js:279)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.js:96)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.js:22)
    in StackView (at createNavigator.js:62)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createAppContainer.js:388)
    in NavigationContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)

finishClassComponent
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:16219:43
performUnitOfWork
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:19455:27
workLoop
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:19489:47
renderRoot
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:19560:21
performWorkOnRoot
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:20280:23
performWork
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:20207:30
performSyncWork
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:20183:20
requestWork
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:20062:26
scheduleWork
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:19934:22
scheduleRootUpdate
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:20451:21
render
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:20921:26
renderApplication
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:68557:59
run
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:68238:28
runApplication
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:68288:28
__callFunction
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2470:49
<unknown>
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2243:31
__guard
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2424:15
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2242:21
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.57.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.9",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.49.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

app.js

```
// In App.js in a new project

import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  }
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Comment: Getting same error have you found a workaround?

Comment: No I was unable to find a solution have gone to react-navigation 2

Answer (score 0):

I've created an example on Github for the solution.

https://github.com/WrathChaos/React-Navigation-v3-Example

First of all, if there is no special purpose for the React Native version of 0.57.5. I suggest that upgrade the RN Version to latest (currently: 0.59.3)

Here is the App.js example code if you do not want to check GitHub :)

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Button
          title="HomeScreen"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Player")}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class PlayerScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>PlayerScreen Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Player: PlayerScreen
});

const MainNavigator = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MainNavigator />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```